# When to use a Thread pool instead of calling new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a JAX-RS/Jersey Rest API which gets a request and needs to do an additional job in a separate thread but I am not sure whether it would be advisable to use a threadpool or not. I expect a lot of requests to this API (a few thousands a day) but I only have a single additional job in the background.

Would it be bad to just create a new Thread each time like this? Any advice would be appreciated. I have not used a ThreadPool before.

```
@Get
@Path("/myAPI")
public Response myCall() {
  // call load in the background
  load();
  ...
  // do main job here
  mainJob();
  ...
}

private void load() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doSomethingInTheBackground();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Edit:**
Just to clarify. I only need a single additional job to run in the background. This job will call another API to log some info and that's it. But it has to do this for every request and I do not need to wait for a response. That's why I thought of just doing this in a new background thread.

**Edit2:**
So this is what I came up with now. Could anyone please tell me if this seems OK (it works locally) and if I need to shutdown the executor (see my comment in the code)?

```
// Configuration class
@Bean (name = "executorService")
public ExecutorService executorService() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
}

// Some other class
@Qualifier("executorService")
@Autowired
private ExecutorService executorService;
....
private void load() {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doSomethingInTheBackground();
        }
    });

    // If I enable this I will get a RejectedExecutionException 
    // for a next request.
    // executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to use a ThreadPool instead of creating a new Thread.

Comment: What if you have 1000 concurrent requests? 1000 threads created is not a good idea. It will consume your server resources and will impact your service respondness

Comment: You can have a beginning of answer in [Oracle's documentation about thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threadpool is a good way of dealing with this for two reasons:

1) you will reuse existing threads in the pool, sort of less overhead
2) more importantly, your system will not get bog down if system goes under attack and some party tries to start zillions of sessions at once because of size of the pool will be preset.

Use of threadpools is not complicated at all. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) more about threadpools. And also take a look at [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of using Executors but I am not sure which kind of pool would be suitable (single, cached, fixed etc) and how to determine the thread pool size? Sorry for the basic questions but as stated before I have not done this before.

Comment: @Diyarbakir well, as gioraschc suggested it all depends what your needs are. So you've gotto start from somewhere and play by the ear and improve your implementation down the road. That's what tests are for. =]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using neither of the approaches you mention, but to use a JMS queue. You can easily embed an ActiveMQ instance in your application. First create one or more separate consumer threads in the background to pick up jobs from the queue.

Then when a request is received just push a message with the job details on the JMS queue. This is a much better architecture and more scalable than fiddling with low level threads or thread pools.

See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493613/best-method-of-triggering-a-shell-script-from-java/1494201#1494201) and [the activeMQ site](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me you don't need to create multiple threads at all.
(although I might be wrong, I don't know the specifics of your task).

Could you perhaps create exactly 1 thread that does background work, and give that thread a `LinkedBlockingQueue` to store the parameters of the `doSomethingInTheBackground` call?

This solution wouldn't work if it is of the utmost importance that the background task starts right away, even when the server is under heavy load. But for example for my most recent task (retrieve text externally, return them to the API caller, then delayed-add the text to the SOLR layer) this was a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: not a good idea. Let's assume one request processing takes 1 sec. So queuing X requests will take optimally X seconds to process. Providing that your server is loaded with numerous requests... well... as a user I'll stop using it;)

Comment: No the thread that actually answers the user gets to reply immediately. That thread just calls `LinkedBlockingQueue.offer()`.